# Clipping roads based on their county

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip, splitting, road, arcgis-10.6

I have both county shape files and all road lines for the state, but I would like to clip the roads based on what county they are in.

How can I do this as a batch or model in the ArcMap application of ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1?

I cannot use Python and I do not have an advanced license (basic only).

Comment: Use the clip tool with a county layer which includes only the county(ies) of interest.  Please explain what you have tried and what is not working as expected.

Comment: I have not tried it yet because I'm doing this for Georgia, which has 159 counties. I know how to do each county individually (including a batch clip, but again... 159 counties), but I wanted to see if there is an easier way to have each county clipped at once.

Comment: If you want to do a separate clip for each county, then use an iterator in model builder to iterate through the counties.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing the use case for the [Split tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split.htm):

> Splits an input with overlaying features to create a subset of output
>   feature classes.
>
> The **Split Field** parameter's unique values form the names of the
>   output feature classes. These are saved in the target workspace.

This tool requires an [Advanced level license](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split.htm#L_).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to an advanced license. Is there a work-around?

Comment: For a work around, see the comments already posted.

Comment: @MrJoshua Yes - several - the most straightforward is to use ArcPy to cursor through the feature class you want to split by, and use the polygon geometry of each feature as input to to each Clip.  The ModelBuilder "equivalent" would be to use an iterator in place of the cursor.

Comment: I would recommend using the Intersect tool (if you have access to it).

Comment: See also the model illustrated in the question at:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241776/iterate-feature-selection-to-clip-raster-in-modelbuilder .  Or see the tutorial here:  https://groundedgis.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/154/ .  These were found with a simple Google search:  https://www.google.com/search?q=arcmap+iterator+features+clip

Comment: @doronwen Using Intersect, presumably in concert with Select, is another way, but I think it less clean, because additional attributes are added in the process and need to be deleted at the end if you want to emulate Split precisely.

Comment: @PolyGeo true, but deleting fields or just ignoring some (I like to freeze the fields I use the most) could be a short task. regardless, it will give him the results he's looking for.